# web audio API not working in chrome localy

Tags: javascript, html, audio, web-audio-api

I have a website that worked great yesterday and today, I've opened it up again and the audio no longer plays

this doesn't happen on firefox nor on the one I've hosted on google drive

here's the html part calling the scripts:

```
<script src="Scripts/frenzyMode.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/DVR media player.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/visualizer.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bodyScript.js"></script>
```

and here's visualizer.js:

```
var canvas, ctx, source, context, analyser, fbc_array, bars, bar_x, bar_width, bar_height;
    function initVisualizer() {
        context = new AudioContext();
        analyser = context.createAnalyser();
        biquad = context.createBiquadFilter();
        gainNode = context.createGain();
        canvas = document.getElementById("visualizer");
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.fillStyle = "#3f3f3f";


        analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.8;
        biquad.frequency.value = 15000;
        gainNode.gain.value = 1;

        source = context.createMediaElementSource(Musique);
        source.connect(biquad);
        biquad.connect(gainNode);
        gainNode.connect(analyser);
        analyser.connect(context.destination);

        $("#frequencyNumber").html(biquad.frequency.value);
        $("#visualizerSensibilityNumber").html(analyser.smoothingTimeConstant);
        $("#gainNumber").html(gainNode.gain.value.toPrecision(3));

        framelooper()
    }

    function framelooper() {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(framelooper);
        fbcArray = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
        analyser.getByteFrequencyData(fbcArray);
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        bars = 50;
        for (i=0; i < bars; i++) {
            bar_x = i * 6;
            bar_width = 5;
            bar_height = -(fbcArray[i] / 1.75); //6 //1.75

            if (visualizerStyle == 1){
                //Simple
                ctx.fillRect(bar_x, canvas.height, bar_width, bar_height);
                $("#visualizerStyleType").html("Simple");
            }
            else if (visualizerStyle == 2) {
                //Reflection
                ctx.fillRect(bar_x, canvas.height/2, bar_width, bar_height/2);
                ctx.fillRect(bar_x, canvas.height/2, bar_width, -bar_height/2);
                $("#visualizerStyleType").html("Reflection");
            }
            else {
                //Two-faced
                ctx.fillRect(0, bar_x, -bar_height, bar_width);
                ctx.fillRect(canvas.width, bar_x, bar_height, bar_width);
                $("#visualizerStyleType").html("Face to Face");
            }
        }
    }
```

I have absolutely no idea why this is happening, as the console is not giving any errors at all

Comment: If the audio is coming from an external domain it could be a cross-origin issue.

Comment: Any errors in the console? Spaces in a file name??

Comment: @epascarello wthere was no error in the console and the files are named 1.mp3, 2.mp3,...

Comment: @lemieuxster it's in a folder were the html page is, and the audio is playing (the audio tag has the music path in the src and the timeline is going, but as soon as I add the visualizer, the music doesn't play)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that Chrome 42 adds CORS restrictions to audio resources, which for some reason were missing, previously.

Possible duplication with this: [Web Audio API no sound playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29708513/web-audio-api-no-sound-playing)

Comment: yeah, it's a cross origin issue, I didn't know they added that in the latest version of chrome, BTW, is there a place where I can see the changes in each version

Comment: I found this website before but it's so messy compared to the one firefox has, I think it's because they mix all the versions together (there's a post about the version 44.0 right before a post about the version 42.0 followed by another version 44.0 update)